# Web Api using parameterized constructor using Autofac

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

I'm converting Smartstore.Net project to WebApi and I want to create an API to get all Product from Smartstore.Net database. Here is my Get property and method:

```
IRepository<Product> productRepository;
public IEnumerable<Product> Get()
{
    var query = from p in _productRepository.Table
        orderby p.Name
        where p.Published && !p.Deleted && p.ShowOnHomePage
        select p;

    var products = query.ToList();
    return products;
}
```

Next step I found that `_productRepository` interface have to exsist through parameterized constructor of Api Controller. Then I have read Autofac do that ([here is link](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/roncain/archive/2012/07/16/dependency-injection-with-asp-net-web-api-and-autofac.aspx)) but i can't find class that implements IRepository interface.

Everyboy used Smartstore.Net can help me create an example API to get all product
or help me found class that implements IRepository interface ?

Thanks alot ! ! !

Comment: `SmartStore.Core.Data.IRepository` or do you intend to remove all dependency on SmartStore?

Comment: Thank you for response. May I find class that implement SmartStore.Core.Data.IRepository<T> interface ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SmartStore.NET 2.0.1 already has integrated support for WebApi. Please [have a look here](https://smartstore.codeplex.com/releases/view/120737).

No need to create your own interface. If you want to expose your custom entities' Api, just inherit from `WebApiEntityController<TEntity, TService>`. The repository and service implementations will be injected automatically for you.

Comment: Please give me an example about WebApiEntityController<TEntity, TService>. Thanks you so much ! ! !